# Example for llvm::CloneBasicBlock

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to find an example code which uses `llvm::CloneBasicBlock`, but can't find it. I am having problems with PHI nodes and problem with instruction domination. So I'll appreciate any good example code which teach how to use `llvm::CloneBasicBlock` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with looking in the LLVM source itself? `CloneBasicBlock` is used in a number of places. The simplest is probably `llvm::CloneFunctionInto`; it should probably be enough to demonstrate how to correctly use the function (in terms of what arguments to pass, etc.)

A more interesting example is in `llvm::LoopUnroll`, which also has to deal with references from PHI nodes.